# Timeout in Email Task in CruiseControl.Net

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to add a Email Publisher Task in Cruise Control but I'm getting the error below.

Publisher threw exception: ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: EmailPublisher exception: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.

I am able to ping the smtp server from the ccnet server from a cmd prompt.

Failed
          Fixed

What could be the cause?

Thanks

Comment: It's timing out, probably while connecting to the smtp server. Check that you set the address of the smtp server correctly in the ccnet config, and check you can ping the smtp server from the ccnet server.

Comment: how do i ping the smtp server from ccnet server, can you please let me know

Comment: You need to connect to the server hosting ccnet, start a command prompt and type "ping SMTP_SERVER_NAME" or "ping SMTP_SERVER_IP" (you neeed to replace the uppercase variables as well).

Comment: im able to ping the SMTP Server from CMD. But still getting the above error Message

Comment: OK. Can you post your email publisher conf here (with obfuscated username/password)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the mail port? I had this same issue the other day, and changed mine to use SSL and port 587, and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Try a telnet to the server + port and see if it is open.